# How would I store multiple instance objects correctly?

Tags: c++, storage, instance

I am making an intermediate/advanced C++ program, a video game to be exact.

Lately I have been noticing that there is a good amount of memory being leaked, and I was wondering if maybe something is wrong with the way I am creating my instances.

Below is a summarized(but originally complex) class:

```
class theObject
{
 //Instance variables
 //Instance functions
};
```

With this object(along with any other objects that I am storing, I have an array index of every different variation template of `theObject`. That part is not important, but the way I am storing them(or in my opinion) is:

```
//NEWER VERSION WITH MORE INFO
void spawnTheObject()
{
 theObject* NewObj=ObjectArray[N];
 //I give the specific copy its individual parameters(such as its spawn location and few edited stats)
 NewObj->giveCustomStats(int,int,int,int);//hard-coded, not actual params
 NewObj->Spawn(float,float,float);
 myStorage.push_back(new theObject(*NewObj));
}


//OLDER VERSION
void spawnTheObject()
    {
     //create a copy of the arrayed object
     theObject* NewObj=new theObject(*ObjectArray[N]);
     //spawn the object(in this case it could be a monster), and I am spawning multiple copies of them obviously
     //then store into the storage object(currently a deque(originally a vector))
     myStorage.push_back(new theObject(*NewObj));
     //and delete the temporary one
     delete NewObj;
    }
```

I am currently using a deque(recently changed from using a vector) but I am seeing no difference in the memory usage. I have though found out from "comment tests" that these spawning functions I have are the reason for the memory leaks. Since this is the wrong way to create/spawn the instances, I was wondering if there is a better way to storing these objects.

tl;dr: What are some better objects to store a non-constant amount of objects and how?

Comment: Use smart pointers and forget about memory leaks.

Comment: "whenever you need either a (non-trivial) copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or destructor, you'll most likely need to implement the others, too"

Comment: What @9dan is referring to is [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you never clear new spawn objects in `myStorage` that causes the memory to increase(as you refer to memory leak). If I am correct your myStorage is declared as below:

```
std::deque<theObject*> myStorage;
```

if you call either of below calls, the pointers to theObject are delete but the real dynamically allocated objects are not deleted.

```
 myStorage.pop_back();
 myStorage.clear();
```

Another small issue in your code, you are making unnecessary object allocate/dellocate in `spawnTheObject()` function.

**How to clean container with pointer type**

You need to iterate through each element in myStorage, delete the object then clear the container, for example:

```
for (std::deque<theObject*>::iterator iter=myStorage.begin();
     iter != myStorage.end(); ++iter)
{
   delete (*iter);
}
myStorage.clear();
```

**Better solution:**

Use smart pointers in `std::deque` or `std::vector`, then when you remove an element from STL container the object the pointer is pointing to is also deleted automatically.

```
 #include <memory>

 std::deque<std::shared_ptr<theObject> > myStorage;
 myStorage.push_back(std::shared_ptr<theObject>(new *ObjectArray[N]));

 mySorage.clear();  // all memories cleared properly, no worries
```

Comment: Okay, I really don't understand why Im constantly getting the error: `shared_ptr is not a member of std`. I added memory to the project, and I even added it to the individual files.

Comment: Alright, I found out that since I was using Gcc I had to use `<tr1/memory>`

Comment: yes if your gcc is not the latest version. shared_ptr was under tr1(technical report 1). it's under std::tr1 namespace as well.

Comment: As for `spawnTheObject`, Which allocation/deallocation is unnecessary? What I am trying to do is take a copy of the arrayed template 'monster' and spawn it to its location, while keeping record of it in a deque. I will update my question to show the changes I have right now.

Comment: Then what do you suggest I use to spawn the object?

Comment: Alright, after using your techniques(I didn't bother with the 'better solution' since there are some contradictions that I ran into(how my program is set up, cant really change it) I managed to kill most of the memory leakage. As for the rest of it I will figure out what else is not being properly removed in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not manually delete your objects from `myStorage` at the end of the game or when they need to be destroyed, there is your memory leak.

```
myStorage.push_back(new theObject(*NewObj));
```

The object being pushed into storage is allocated by you, so it should be destroyed by you when it needs to disappear.

Also I do not understand the need for the intermediate `NewObj` object, it isnt a memory leak but it is an unnecessary performance cost, 1 allocation/deallocation + 1 copy.

As Forever mentioned, your best bet is to start using smart pointers, either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (only if c++11).

Comment: Wait, so Should I only be using `shared_ptr` for the deque? Or for every instance I create?

Comment: the deque should be of type `std::deque<std::shared_ptr<theObject> >`

Comment: Why not a `deque<theObject>`? It is obvious from he code sample that @Molma is happy for `theObject` instances to be copied and doesn't need polymorphic cloning so dynamic allocation and smart pointers are an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Depends if the rest of the code is written to treat the deque as the Owner of the code. If so then you are right, storing by value is sufficient. However certain parts of the code like sorting might take a performance hit.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Actually, `deque<theObhect>` is the only thing I could think of when storing a non-constant number of objects...Yes I would like to make sure I am not causing a massive amount of memory leaks, but I still want to make sure that I will be copying the necessary amount of 'monsters' as well. What I really need is a way to copy and later delete the 'monsters' so the memory is freed. the monsters can be remade when needed.

Comment: The container doesn't necessarily need to contain smart pointers, as long as it's taking ownership of the objects and they are being transferred to another owner or deleted when removed from the container. Alternatively you could look @ boost's ptr containers. The only problem then is the free pointer between allocation and insertion into the container (not exception safe). You could temporarily use a smart pointer and release into the container.

Comment: Also I cannot use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` since I do not have C++11

Comment: @Molma: `shared_ptr` implementations exist for C++03.